# How to change position of search bar in mobile when user clicks on it

Tags: javascript, css, html, angular, typescript

I am working on a open source project of a search engine developed using Angular. For smaller screen sizes,the position of search bar is in middle and as soon as user clicks in it gets hidden behind keypad terminal.Anyone please tell how to detect this event and change position of search bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind custom or click event to change position dynamically using CSS.

Or you can use ngStyle like

```
    <button class="my-btn" [ngStyle]="setStyles()">Call to Action</button>



setStyles() {
    let styles = {
        // CSS property names
        'font-style':  this.someProperty ? 'italic' : 'normal',     // italic
        'font-weight': this.anotherProperty ? 'bold'   : 'normal',  // normal
    };
    return styles;
}
```